# Openvpn unable to retain capabilities after change uid to nobody

Tags: openvpn

Today I tried to move my OpenVPN server installation from one machine to another. Both of them are Arch Linux, I copied configs from one to another. But on a new machine I encountered this while starting OpenVPN visa systemd service

```
Mar 12 17:20:36 hz-vm-flwn-1 openvpn[2042]: capng_change_id('nobody','nobody') failed retaining capabilities: -9: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Mar 12 17:20:36 hz-vm-flwn-1 openvpn[2042]: Unable to retain capabilities
Mar 12 17:20:36 hz-vm-flwn-1 openvpn[2042]: GID set to nobody
Mar 12 17:20:36 hz-vm-flwn-1 openvpn[2042]: setgroups('nobody') failed: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Mar 12 17:20:36 hz-vm-flwn-1 openvpn[2042]: Exiting due to fatal error
```

Difference between machines is basically versions of packages, for OpenVPN which is 2.5.5 vs 2.6.1.

I tried to add different capabilities to service, change user and group to root, nothing works.

Any advice where to look is appreciated.

Comment: same issue on my end as well, try to open a bug report here https://bugs.archlinux.org/?project=1&string=openvpn

Comment: I'm actually not sure whether this is Arch specific problem or not. I'll do a little digging on the weekend, if unsuccessful, then I'll try to file a bug.

Comment: Also I must say that I am thinking about abandoning OpenVPN completely in favor of Wireguard, it works pretty well, especially for private VPN server and now supported by wide variety of devices, including even budget routers.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone still looking for an answer, [look no further](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=284246).

TLDR: Arch introduced it's own unprivileged user `openvpn` with group `network` as default and the `--user` and `--group` options can be safely deleted / commented out from the config.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here on Arch, and it persists in 2.6.2. Downgrading to openvpn-2.6.0-1 worked for me (for now).